# In Opencart How should i edit the "Order By" product_id in mini cart?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

i still not found where place should i edit the "ORDER BY product_id" in mini cart.

I want the list order is ORDER BY Alphabetical, that should be iPhone first, MacBook is last.

How should i edit the controller file ?

[image: This is my image]

Answer (score 0):

By default opencart from controller calls model/catalog/product and function getProducts(), so you need to edit controller with additional data:

/catalog/controller/common/cart.php

```
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
```

By idea, it should look like:

```
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts($data_f['pd.name']) as $product) {
```

Can't test it right now, but if you have demo server, try it.